# chaquo pyException ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'quaternion'

Tags: android, python-3.x, pip, quaternions, chaquopy

I am trying to integrate python into my android java project with the below changes on the Gradle file.
But it generates the module error.  But I have given the same module to the pip installation list. It installed successfully but still showing the same error.

Please see below error :
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: com.chaquo.python.PyException: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'quaternion'

app level gradle :

```
 plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.chaquo.python'

}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        python {
            buildPython "C:/Users/Bridge Global/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe"

            pip {
                // A pip requirement specifier, with or without a version number:

                install "scipy"
                install "numpy"
                install "quaternion"
                install "pandas"
                install "matplotlib"

            }


        }
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }

            sourceSets {
                main {
                    python{
                        srcDir "src/main/python"
                    }
                }
            }
        }



    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

project level gradle :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://chaquo.com/maven" }    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0"
        classpath "com.chaquo.python:gradle:8.0.0"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Main Activity

```
if (! Python.isStarted()) {
   
    Python.start(new AndroidPlatform(this));
    Python py = Python.getInstance();
    PyObject pyObject =py.getModule("backend");
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in [the documentation](https://sot.github.io/Quaternion/module.html), the module name is `Quaternion` with a capital Q. The capitalization doesn't matter with pip, but it does matter in `import` statements.

Or perhaps you meant to install the pip package [numpy-quaternion](https://pypi.org/project/numpy-quaternion/), whose Python module name is `quaternion` with a lower-case q. Unfortunately this is a native package which [isn't currently available for Chaquopy](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/392), but there are some other pure-Python alternatives which you may find useful:

- [pyquaternion](https://pypi.org/project/pyquaternion/) (the most popular)
- [quaternionic](https://pypi.org/project/quaternionic/) (from the same developer as numpy-quaternion)

Comment: Tried this. I think these two modules are different because the use cases of the quaternion module are not supporting on Quaternion.

Comment: OK, I've edited my question to mention another package which you may be thinking of.